# How to enable/disable WiFi from an application?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi

I want to enable/disable wifi from my Android application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); // true or false to activate/deactivate wifi
```

You also need to request the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: yes, don't forget to add use permission in your manifest android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: @Codii, I know this is old, but I am trying to do this within a dialogfragment. However, it says "Cannot resolve method 'getSystemService(java.lang.String)' I am not sure on what I need to do. And I have those permissions

Comment: Worked for me thanks and you can check `wifi` if enable use `false` and if disable use `true`

Answer (score 17):

To enable/disable WiFi in your application you need to use WiFiManager class. Create an Object of WiFiManager class to get the services of WiFi.

```
WifiManager wifi;
wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);//Turn off Wifi

wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);//Turn on Wifi
```

And you have to put the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

To get the whole sample code of enable/disable Wifi in android with UI visit [this website](http://androidfordev.blogspot.in/2012/06/enabledisable-wifi-in-android.html)

Comment: This is a more complete answer. Includes all the required permissions.

Comment: when i do it in my project, but when these code is executed, the system will give a prompt says the app is trying to use wlan whether allows it. and it appears every time! can i enable wlan without the prompt window .

Answer (score 5):

try this code

```
 Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);  
            startActivityForResult(gpsOptionsIntent,0);
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to open settings. i want to disable or enable directly from my app.

Answer (score 4):

To enable/disable wifi from an app in **Android Q (Android 10)** use **Settings Panel**:

```
val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
```

On previous versions of Android this should work (appropriate permissions should be added to AndroidManifest file, see answers above):

```
(context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager)?.apply { isWifiEnabled = true /*or false*/ }
```

Resulting code might look something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 0)
} else {
    (context?.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as? WifiManager)?.apply { isWifiEnabled = true /*or false*/ }
}
```

Where `context` is a reference to `android.content.Context` object.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void disableWifi(Context context, Boolean bool) {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(bool)
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
    else
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, one should also explain how and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    toggleWiFi(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi Enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    toggleWiFi(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wi-Fi Disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void toggleWiFi(boolean status){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (status && !wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        } else if (!status && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Add User Permission in Manifest Files