# Ask user to turn on Wi-Fi

Tags: android, android-intent, wifi

I have an app which almost always needs to know the user location.

When I need to access a location, I do this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MapScreen.this);
builder.setTitle("MyAppName");
builder.setMessage("The location service is off. Do you want to turn it on?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Enable location",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(
                                    final DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                    final int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        });
builder.setNegativeButton("Continue without location", null);
builder.create().show();
```

However, the GPS gives me some info that isn't always precise enough. Wi-Fi always gives me enough precission, so I want to ask the user to turn on the Wi-Fi the same way I ask them to turn on the location. I do not want to just turn it on, I want the user to be notified about it, and to manually enable it.

Is there any Intent to bring the WiFi menu to the user?

Comment: you can try this also [Enable wifi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5674685/1083388)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following intent shows the wireless settings such as Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Mobile networks:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

For the complete list of Settings: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

For the documentation on the `startActivity` method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

(keep in mind `startActivity` is just throw and forget, if you want to capture the response of what the user did out there you could instead call `startActivityForResult`, probably not needed in this case)

Comment: Thank you! Accepted answer because of the complete list of settings ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers were quotting the "Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS", but it is too general, as it is going to open the settings of the general wireless connection while the question is about wifi only.
I'm using "Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS" as follows

```
Intent turnWifiOn = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(turnWifiOn);
```

Note: It's not going to open just a dialog, but an activity instead.