# Disable Wifi or 3g Process

Tags: android, android-wifi, gsm, 3g, umts

i want to implement in my app (ANDROID) this function: when a process or app runs or start, all the connection disabled, for example: when i open facebook i want to disable wi-fi or 3g.
I searched on google, but i didn't found anything, if you don't undersant, you can ask me for explain.
I wish the wifi when I open an app is turned off, or when I open an app to deactivate 3g, and when I close it or leave it in the background are reactivated both the 3g if wi-fi is active if it is active. I did not understand how to do, I have half a mind to see which of the two types of connectivity are using the user at the moment, but for the restto nothing.

Sorry for my English but i'm not English :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post shows you how to disable wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674333/android-how-to-enable-disable-wireless-from-an-application)

Perhaps you can [check what processes are currently running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-in-android). Once you see Facebook you can disable what you want.