# How to request Wi-Fi be turned on?

Tags: android, wifi

How do you prompt the user to turn on WiFi?  I understand how to force WiFi to be turned on, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674333/how-to-enable-disable-wifi-from-an-application), but my goal is to have the user be able to choose.

I have search the [WiFiManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)) and other similar classes with no luck.  Thanks in advance!

**Example of my goal, as done in Bluetooth**

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

Comment: I guess you thought about that already, but if it is really not possible as with Bluetooth, would a notification do it?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but fewer permissions would be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Why not Create a alert box with two buttons? Based on what the user chooses you could either enable or do nothing with the WIFI.

Like this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to turn WIFI ON?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); // true or false to activate/deactivate wifi
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Do Nothing or Whatever you want.
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Hope that helps. My goal here was to replicate the Bluetooth alert box somewhat.